# Python List of Dictionaries iterations

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What wrong with this code, return empty list?

```
week = []
for d in week:
    day_num  = calendar.weekday(d.year,d.month,d.day)
    day_name = calendar.day_name[day_num]
    daydate = { "day_name":day_name,
                "day":d.day,
                "month":d.month,
                "year":d.year,
               }
    week.append(daydate)
return week
```

Comment: I guess `for d in week` should be `for d in something_else`

Comment: week is an empty list.  The for d value is none.

Answer (score 3):

Because the list `week` is empty initially, the for loop is iterated zero times.

Answer (score 0):

Your `week` list is set as `[]` just before the `for` statement, so the loop doesn't have any element to iterate on. You have to either:

- remove this `week = []` if `week` has already been declared
- add elements in the list.
- fixed your code. It's maybe not on `week` that you want to iterate but on another variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar 
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  

def generateDays(start_date,weeks):
   days=7*weeks
   week = []  
   for day in np.arange(days):
        a_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date + timedelta(days=int(day)))
        day_num  = calendar.weekday(a_date.year,a_date.month,a_date.day)
        day_name = calendar.day_name[day_num]
        daydate = { "day_name":day_name,
            "day":a_date.day,
            "month":a_date.month,
            "year":a_date.year,
           }
        week.append(daydate)
    return week    


print(generateDays(date.today(),2))
```

output

```
 [{'day_name': 'Wednesday', 'day': 16, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Thursday', 'day': 17, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Friday', 'day': 18, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Saturday', 'day': 19, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Sunday', 'day': 20, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Monday', 'day': 21, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Tuesday', 'day': 22, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Wednesday', 'day': 23, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Thursday', 'day': 24, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Friday', 'day': 25, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Saturday', 'day': 26, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Sunday', 'day': 27, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Monday', 'day': 28, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}, {'day_name': 'Tuesday', 'day': 29, 'month': 6, 'year': 2021}]
```